# Как в js получить изображение товара Opencart

Tags: javascript, opencart

переделал мини корзину в хедере на дефолтном шаблоне Opencart 3 и вместо изображения поставил заглушку при наведении на которую всплывает основное изображение товара, но получить путь к изображению товара в скрипте не могу. Так как это корзина, то товаров может быть несколько и соответственно при наведении на свою заглушку должно всплывать свое изображение товара, ниже добавил часть кода

```
<div class="small-img" style="border-radius:10px;padding-top:5px;background:white;position:absolute;display:none;z-index:10005;box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);width:120px;height:110px;max-width:120px;max-height:110px;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;left: 50px;"></div>
<td class="text-center">
      {% if product.thumb %} 
      <a href="{{ product.thumb }}" title="{{ product.name }}" target="blank" onmouseover="show_small_img(event, '{{ product.thumb }}');" onmouseout="$('.small-img').hide();"><img src="image/image_product.png" width="16"></a>
      {% endif %}
</td>

<script> 
function show_small_img(image){
$('.small-img').html('<img src="тут путь до изображения" style="height:100px;width: 100px;">');
$('.small-img').css({"width": "120px", "text-align":"center"});
$('.small-img').show();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

А что если в выводе изображения прописать `data-src="{{product.thumb}}"` и в скрипте обращаться уже к data-src?